# How to blend color with paint bucket?

Tags: inkscape, fill, blending

Say I have a red object. I fill it blue with paint bucket. But I want the final color is blue+red=purple, not blue. And if the object has gradual red, then the final color is gradual purple as well. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. If you have a red filled object, you don't need to use the bucket fill tool. Just select the object and change the fill colour to purple.  If you want a gradient instead, use the Gradient tool, and edit the gradient with the required colours.

Comment: That's one way, but if I want to fill multiple objects which has different existing colors, then I have to select each of them. While with the bucket tool I can just click and done

Comment: That's not an efficient method to change fill colours. It will add extra objects, and the final SVG will be bigger than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use layer blending modes in Inkscape to overlay one colour over another. You may have to experiment with these to find the optimal blend mode.

However, what you are suggesting is generally a bad idea if your intent is to create a working SVG for the web, or perhaps even if you are outputting as PDF.

If you use multiple layers/blending modes (see *note below) to change colours of underlying objects, you will find that different browsers may render these differently. Support for some of these is a bit flakey in some browsers, and probably totally non-existent/messed up for PDFs.

Not only that, but using the Paint Bucket tool creates additional filled objects, which will increase the file size of your SVG. and could possibly also affect rendering times in browsers.

Instead, it's better to keep the design as simple as possible: that means shapes and paths with strokes and fills applied directly to each. Don't be tempted to use layers/layer blending modes/effects.

*Note: These are absolutely fine if you intend to output as a raster image.